# How to draw pgraphics with different opacity out of an array?

Tags: arrays, processing, opacity, pgraphics

i am trying to draw this 5 rectangles with an array but they have all the same opacity...
But they should have different but i dont now why?
Does someone can help me?
Thank you in advance :)
Sebastian

```
PGraphics[] pgArray = new PGraphics[5];

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  background(255);

  for (int i = 0; i<pgArray.length; i++) {
    pgArray[i] = createGraphics(500, 500);
  }
}

void draw() {

  for (int i = 0; i < pgArray.length; i++) {
    pgArray[i].beginDraw();
    pgArray[i].fill(0, (255/pgArray.length)*i+1);
    pgArray[i].rect(20*i, 20*i, 50, 50);
    pgArray[i].endDraw();
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < pgArray.length; i++){
    image(pgArray[i],0,0);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems: Your code does not clear the stage between frames and nor does it clear the PGraphics objects between frames. As opacity is additive, the rectangles would each reach full opacity within a few frames since you are drawing them on top of each other.

First, to refresh the background each frame:

- Insert a call to `background(255);` at the top of the `draw()` loop.

Then, to clear the PGraphics objects you can either:

- Move your rectangle drawing loop into `setup()`, so it runs once only.

Or

- Insert a call to `pgArray[i].clear();` after `pgArray[i].beginDraw();`.

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: Of course, you are right. But if i put clear() after the beginnDraw() there is no gradient they are all black... But they schould have all different opacities...

Comment: You need to do both: clear the background and PGraphics each frame.

Comment: @mycycle nvm forgott to put background(255) in the draw loop :) Much Thanks!!